# How to check elements are rendered with a specific sorting with react-testing-library?

Tags: react-testing-library

With its user-centric approach, my understanding of RTL is that testing sorting of elements should look something like.

```js
const foo = queryByText('foo');
const bar = queryByText('bar');
expect(foo).toBeInTheDocument();
expect(bar).toBeInTheDocument();
expect(foo).toShowBefore(bar); // THIS IS MY PSEUDOCODE
```

However, I couldn't find a `.toShowBefore()` or equivalent function in RTL.
What's the correct way to test that content is displayed in a certain order?

Comment: https://www.atkinsondev.com/post/react-testing-library-order/ looks promising but I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [compareDocumentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition).

For example

```
const e1 = getByText('a');
const e2 = getByText('b');
expect(e1.compareDocumentPosition(e2)).toBe(2);
```

Here `getByText` is returned from the `render` function.

Comment: Very good if you cannot add a test-id

Comment: adding test-id is too manual and also polluting codes

Comment: If you're expecting 'a' to come before 'b' then the result should be `Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING` (which is `4`)

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe React Testing Library has an idiomatic way to do this. But if you can parse your DOM, then you should be able to get the textContent of various Elements and assert on that.

```
const select = screen.getByTestId('select');
const children = select.children;

expect(children.item(0)?.textContent).toEqual('Interface A');
expect(children.item(1)?.textContent).toEqual('Interface B');
expect(children.item(2)?.textContent).toEqual('Interface C');
```

Answer (score 4):

You could give each row a test id:

```
<tr data-testid='row'>...</tr>
```

and then expect the rows to be in order:

```
const rows = screen.getAllByTestId('row')

expect(within(rows[0]).queryByText('A')).toBeInTheDocument()
expect(within(rows[1]).queryByText('B')).toBeInTheDocument()
expect(within(rows[2]).queryByText('C')).toBeInTheDocument()
```